# Assembly: reading lines of assembly instructions

Tags: parsing, assembly, x86

I am working on a program that is to read in input from a file that includes assembly instructions and then output whether each line includes a label, opcode, oper1, oper2, or comment. Here is what I have so far:

```
        .model  small
        .8086

        .data
line        db      'LABEL=','$'
opcode      db      'OPCODE=','$'
oper1       db      'OPER1=','$'
oper2       db      'OPER2=','$'
com         db      'COMMENT=',13,10,13,10,'$'
filemsg     db      '... end of file',13,10,1Ah,'$'

        .code

start:      
        mov     ax,@data
        mov     ds,ax

progloop:
        mov     ah,8
        int     21h

        cmp     al,1Ah
        je      eof

        mov     dl,al
        mov     ah,2
        int     21h

        cmp     dl,3Ah    ; this is where I would check for a colon. incomplete for now

        cmp     dl,0Ah
        je      eol

        jmp     progloop

eol:
        mov     dx,offset line
        mov     ah,9
        int     21h
        mov     dx,offset opcode
        mov     ah,9
        int     21h
        mov     dx,offset oper1
        mov     ah,9
        int     21h
        mov     dx,offset oper2
        mov     ah,9
        int     21h
        mov     dx,offset com
        mov     ah,9
        int     21h

        jmp     progloop

eof:       
        mov     dx,offset filemsg
        mov     ah,9
        int     21h

exit:       mov     ax,4c00h
        int     21h
        end     start
```

The program is basically supposed to output like so:

```
Addval:   add   [salary],1000   ; this line has all five operands
LABEL=Y   OPCODE=Y   OPER1=Y   OPER2=Y   COMMENT=Y

testit:                         ; a label and a comment
LABEL=Y   OPCODE=N   OPER1=N   OPER2=N   COMMENT=Y
```

I am not sure how to properly go about this. Should I make a `linemsg` and have it keep track of LABEL=, OPCODE=, etc? How should I keep track of the Y/N flags?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, but not perfect, would be something like this...

First determine if there's a comment on a line and then remove it from there (either physically or shorten the effective line length to the position of the first semicolon).

Then see if there's a colon in what remains. If there is, to the left of it is a label name. You can remove it (or again, just skip past it, pretending that the line begins after the colon).

If there's still anything left, the first item is an opcode. If there's anything after it, it's the operands (one or multiple separated with commas).

This is not a perfect solution because in various x86 assemblers there are a number of more complex constructs supported, for example, if a segment is specified, there will be a colon that has nothing to do with labels:

```
mov al, byte ptr es:[bx]
```

In the above `mov al, byte ptr es` is not a label.

Or you may have an array declared like in the below. The array's name isn't an opcode, it's effectively a label, but there's no colon after it:

```
MyArray db 1,2,3,4,5 ; array of 5 bytes
```

And you may also encounter punctuators inside of character and string literals that do not separate the line into labels, operands and comments:

```
MyString db ':,a;'
```

Here, `MyString db '` isn't a label just because there's a colon after it. `a` isn't an operand just because there's a comma right before it. And, finally, `;'` isn't a comment just because there's a semicolon in there.

To fully support all these possibilities you'd need to implement a more complex solution, likely involving a parsing state machine.

Comment: I have to disagree with this answer - at least the first part. I'm pretty sure the entire point of the exercise is to develop a tokenizer; recognizing keywords, literals, and variables; and finally assembling the code into bytecode. Writing code that targets a specific file or even a specific language defeats the learning purpose. There is a process to writing system software and the process is defined for a reason.

Comment: @Sparafusile: Please note that the are x86 instructions with 3 operands (e.g. SHLD and SHRD), so, in that respect the given task is limited not only to a specific language, but also to a subset of it. We haven't been told anything about the intentions, expectations, general-purpose tokenizers, actual assemblying of source code and we aren't in position to judge on SO how teaching is done somewhere else and attempt to change it. I think there are more appropriate ways and places for that. Also, this is an assignment; expectations & processes existing in the industry don't apply in full here.